# How many temporary files will be deleted on every cron run?

Tags: 8, cron

I was just wondering if anyone knew how many files the Drupal cron removes from your tmp/ directory per cron run? Is it limited to 100 at a time? Where can I see this information?

Comment: Are you asking about files being deleted from the /tmp directory on your server? or temporary Drupal file entities (i.e. from /admin/content/files?status=0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the query is set to 100 items per cron run. You can see the associated code for it in [file_cron()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.x/core/modules/file/file.module#L750-755).

> ```
> $fids = Drupal::entityQuery('file')
>   ->accessCheck(FALSE)
>   ->condition('status', FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT, '<>')
>   ->condition('changed', REQUEST_TIME - $age, '<')
>   ->range(0, 100)
>   ->execute();
> ```